# Странный баг с куками

Tags: javascript, cookie

Доброго времени суток! Обнаружил странный баг - если поставть куку:

```
document.cookie = 'admin_lang=ru; expires='+date.toUTCString();
```

перезагрузить страницу и снова поставить эту куку с другим значением, то кук с таким именем станет две: одна с новым, вторая со старым значением! В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: какой браузер ? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/VL5E2/ проблема не повторяется.

Comment: Проблема не в браузере, а в моем сайте. Только я понятия не имею, в чем может быть проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

думаю вы задаете куку с разными доменами или путями.

Comment: И действительно. Спасибо.